# ruby regex make sub stop at first match

Tags: ruby, regex, substitution

I am trying to replace a specific pattern in a text string.
That pattern is a href containing the word "sak".

My script currently looks like this:

```
ccontent=ccontent.sub(/<a .+?href=\"([^\"]+)\"[^\>]*>Sak<\/a>/,  '')
```

The problem is that this replaces the entire string. (the string contains two links).
The problem is somewhere around the `a .+?" symbols, it runs through the link i want to Replace entirely and goes into the next link and replaces that whole link as well.

But I want it to STOP when the first pattern match is reached so that it only erases "sak" link.

How do i make the pattern match stop at the first time it reaches the 'href'?

Answer (score 4):

Your expression is greedy, because `.+?` will actually keep matching any character as long as the pattern still matches.

Just use the `[^>]*` character set you're already using at the end of the regex:

```
ccontent.sub(/<a [^>]*href=\"([^\"]+)\"[^>]*>Sak<\/a>/,  '')
```